# RouterLink with button and *ngif

Tags: angular

I am using *ngIf to route to a different page based on a variable. When I click on the button nothing happens. The links does exists. This is my code:

```
        <button mat-button   >
          <span class="label" >Micro Memoirs</span>
          <div *ngIf="signedIn else elseBlock">
            <a [routerLink]="['/story']"></a>
          </div>
          <ng-template #elseBlock>
          <a [routerLink]="['/auth']">  </a>
          </ng-template>
       </button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily need the `*ngIf` directive. You could include the condition directly in the `[routerLink]` binding. Try the following

```html
<button mat-button [routerLink]="signedIn ? ['/story'] : ['/auth']">
  <span class="label" >Micro Memoirs</span>
</button>
```

One quick way to remember this is that whenever property binding `[]` or interpolation `{{ }}` is involved, they are interpreted as expressions.